# Could I use one Django Modelform in 2 scenerios with different number of fields used?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views, modelform

I'm new to Django `Formmodel` and `Class-Based View` and so confused by those. Suppose I have a model Post with some fields such as `owner`, `content`, `time_created`... Could I create a formmodel from it and use it in two `Class-Based View`s with different numbers of fields used, like:

- One `CreateView` that uses only `content` field, other fields will be automatically added by code, or an `UpdateView` that uses the same field to allow users to edit their posts.
- One `DetailView` uses all fields to show info about posts when users want to see post details.

Please guide me with this problem. Thanks all ^^

Comment: `DetailView` does not need a form. Since you want the same fields in both `CreateView` and `UpdateView` you can use the same form class for them.

Comment: ok thanks again bro, lots of help from you to day @AbdulAzizBarkat